# What's the cheapest type of package to assemble?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly, cost

Say you have a microcontroller that you want to use on a production board. Most microcontrollers come in several different packages. Assuming all the packages cost the same, what typically would be the cheapest one to use in terms of board assembly? Also, assuming that space wasnt a problem?

For example, the atmega88p comes in PDIP, TQFP, and MLF. Is one more/less expensive to assemble than the other? I'm talking about from the whole process, from board production to assembly.

Comment: Go look at the pricing on the website. "Cheap" is relative, because you can mount a PDIP in your garage. You can do the other SMTs if you have the equipment, and if you're super fancy and making millions of units you can do a die-bonded chip (epoxy blob). Those are all costs that factor into 'cheap'.

Comment: So it depends on 1) what you want 2) what your capabilities are and 3) how many you're making

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on the assembly house, I think.  If they have to make special arrangements for the particular package, then it could be significantly more expensive.  I think these days, many assembly houses are set up to do mostly surface mount, so through hole stuff could be significantly more expensive.  Especially if you're mixing surface mount and through hole or have through hole on both sides.  As for SMT packages...I think the costs will be similar, though they could charge more for parts like QFN and BGA.